# How to destroy caphlist to create new?

Tags: jquery, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, caph-framework

I am working on tizen web app by using caphList. I am using ajax to fetch data from api and after getting response I set in caphlist by this code:

```
// Reset container before set data
$('#sub_cate_list').html("");

$('#sub_cate_list').caphList({
    items : items,
    template: 'sub-cate-template',
    containerClass : 'list',
    direction: 'vertical',
    initialItemIndex: 0,
    onFocusItemView: function(context) {
        // Assign inner category index
        SUB_CAT_INDEX = {rowIndex: context.rowIndex, itemIndex: context.itemIndex};                             
    }                       
});
```

Before setting data in caphlist i am using ***html()*** method of jquery to reset the container and it's working fine But when i click on another category to load same ui but new category data then focus in not working.

**Code to set focus:**

```
$.caph.focus.activate();
let controllerProvider = $.caph.focus.controllerProvider.getInstance();
controllerProvider.setDepth(0);         
controllerProvider.focus(0);
```

Caphlist Template:

```
<div class="shows_container_list" id="sub_cate_list"></div> <!-- container element -->

            <!-- template view -->
            <script id="sub-cate-template" type="text/template">
                <div class="home_listbox item" focusable data-focusable-initial-focus="<%=(index===0)?true:false%>" data-focusable-depth="1">
                    <div class="shows_innerbox">
                        <div class="shows_box" data-uri="<%= item.uri %>">
                            <img src="<%= item.image %>">
                            <div class="shows_textlist text_bright"><%= item.text %></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </script>
```

So i think destroy method of caphlist will work but i do not know how to use this. So could someone please suggest how to use destroy method?

***What i want to do:***

I have two category "today" and "tomorrow" and when i click first time on "today" or "tomorrow" then on next screen focus is working properly but after coming back to category screen and again if i click on "today" and "tomorrow" then on next screen focus in not working.

If anyone think I am not doing in right way please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Please post the sub-cate-template HTML code as well.

Comment: @burakk I have also added html code, please check.